# how to redirect my login page to the home page using FLASK, Python, MySQLdb

Tags: python, flask, mysql-python

The code I am using is as follows. I want to know how I can redirect my login page to the home page. I have tried a lot of things like recreating my database in mysql, rewriting the code again and again, but still when I enter the right login details, the page comes back to the login page and does not redirect to the home page like it should.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import MySQLdb.cursors
import re


app=Flask(__name__)


app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'remotemysql.com'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = '7CNYamZi6G'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'QgKp7RwBhr'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = '7CNYamZi6G'

mysql = MySQL(app)


@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/adm_login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def adm_login():
    msg = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'adm_user' in request.form and 'adm_pass' in request.form:
        adm_user = request.form['adm_user']
        adm_pass = request.form['adm_pass']

        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM user_mgmt WHERE adm_user = %s AND adm_pass = %s', (adm_user, adm_pass))
        account = cursor.fetchone()
        if account:
            session['loggedin'] = True
            session['id'] = account['adm_id']
            session['username'] = account['adm_user']
            return 'Logged in successfully!'
        else:
            msg = 'Incorrect username/password!'
    return render_template('adm_login.html', msg=msg)

@app.route('/home')
def home():
    if 'loggedin' in session:
        return render_template('home.html', username=session['username'])
    return redirect(url_for('adm_login'))

@app.route('/profile')
def profile():
    if 'loggedin' in session:
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM 7CNYamZi6G.user_mgmt WHERE adm_id = %s', [session['id']])
        account = cursor.fetchone()
        return render_template('profile.html', account=account)
    return redirect(url_for('adm_login'))


@app.route('/admin_show', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def admin_show():
    show = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'from_date' in request.form and 'through_date' in request.form:
        from_date = request.form['from_date']
        through_date = request.form['through_date']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM ach_mgmt WHERE Date_Ach BETWEEN %s AND %s', (from_date, through_date))
        show = cursor.fetchall()
    return render_template('admin_show.html', show=show)

@app.route('/delete/<string:track_id>', methods = ['GET'])
def delete(track_id):
    flash("Record Has Been Deleted Successfully")
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM ach_mgmt WHERE id=%s", (track_id,))
    mysql.connection.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('admin_show'))


@app.route('/update/<string:track_id>',methods=['POST','GET'])
def update(track_id):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        track_id = request.form['track_id']
        Field_Ach = request.form['Field_Ach']
        Name_Ach = request.form['Name_Ach']
        Level_Ach = request.form['Level_Ach']
        Position_Ach = request.form['Position_Ach']
        Date_Ach = request.form['Date_Ach']
        Remarks = request.form['Remarks']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("UPDATE ach_mgmt SET Field_Ach=%s, Name_Ach=%s, Level_Ach=%s, Position_Ach=%s, Date__Ach=%s, Remarks=%s WHERE track_id=%s", (Field_Ach, Name_Ach, Level_Ach, Position_Ach, Date_Ach, Remarks, track_id))
        flash("Data Updated Successfully")
        mysql.connection.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('admin_show'))

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('loggedin', None)
    session.pop('id', None)
    session.pop('username', None)
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning `return 'Logged in successfully!'` in the `adm_login` try using `return redirect(url_for('home'))`.

I hope you are not using this somewhere in production as your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: still not working, yes its just a personal project

Comment: my database connection is successful, so the only problem that could arise should be in the code

Comment: The database has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Have you tried printing the `account`? What do you get there?

Comment: how do I print the account ?